# start simulation/run python script from plotly dash

Tags: python, dashboard, plotly-dash

Maybe this has been answered before, but I couldn't find anything. Anyway  I have a simulation that I wrote in python using simpy. Now I want to display the results in a dashboard using plotly dash. The thing is that I have a couple of different versions of the simulation, and I would like to be able to choose the version I want on the dashboard (dropdown menu) and then the chosen version should trigger a run of the corresponding python file. The results of the run will then be shown on the dashboard.

I could first run all of the simulation files myself before showing the results in dash, but that would be too complicated. Anyone tried that before?

Comment: Plotly Dash allows you to write "apps" which allow the interactivity you're looking for.  Take a look here: https://dash.plot.ly/gallery  Click on some of the source code links to see how the examples are built.

Comment: Simply package your simulations in a module and then import them into your Dash application. You can then trigger a callback function to be fired when your Dropdown value is changed.